# How to get MIDI instrument model from device ID code?

Tags: midi

Is there any public database that allows to get the model name from the device ID code (returned in reply to the f0 7e 7f 06 01 f7 SysEx) ?

Answer (score 1):

The MIDI Manufacturer's Association maintains a [list of ID's on their site](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/manid.php), seems you'll probably have to scrape it in order to get it into a database which you can query. There is no authoritative database of devices; making your own would likely take quite a bit of time. Also the list on the MMA's website is not updated terribly often...

Keep in mind that not all manufacturers bother to register their ID's, but at least this list is better than nothing.

Comment: MMA website was the first place I visited in my search, but unfortunately, they only have a list of manufacturers, not a list of models. And even that does not seem complete...

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't read your question very carefully. I've edited my answer accordingly.